# Xamarin.Forms Image Slider in Xaml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to do image slider. But I could not do show more images on xaml side.  Here is my code;

Xaml:

```
     <Image  //first image
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="{Binding Hotel.HotelImages[0].FullPath}" />

     <Image //second image
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Source="{Binding Hotel.HotelImages[1].FullPath}" />
```

when I try this, it show me last image but i want to show both of them like carousel.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/C74tr.png ----I want like this

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElnFn.png ---- its my page

Comment: It is not clear what you have there. Are your images within a grid or stacklayout. can you please add all your contentpage xaml code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, seem like you could use the "new" `Xamarin.Forms`' `CarouselView` from Xamarin:

Nuget: [CarouselView](http://%20CarouselView%20NuGet)

Ref: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

```
<cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos}" x:Name="CarouselZoos">
    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
  </cv:CarouselView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ImageGallery](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageGallery) from Xlabs.